# Calling a method in its own class gives me errors c# VS code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, console, static-methods

I was trying to figure out if I can call a method in its own class (I believe we can) so I created some very simple code:

```
public class CalMethod
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public int Calculator(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    int result = Calculator(2,3);      
}
```

When I try to do `int result= Calculator (2,3);` I saw an error: a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property. Why this Calculator method needs to be static to be called in its own class? -yes I was trying to do a console app, but this class is not the main class from the program project.

And another thing that confuses me is that I was not able to find 'Calculator' from the list in its own class when typing 'Cal..', when the method is non-static. So I have to create a constructor of this class, and instantiating a new object to allow me to use a non-static method?

Please help.
Thank you!

Comment: C# doesn't let you execute code from the *body* of a class. Code which is run must go into methods on that class. E.g. you could call it from your console app's `Main` method: `static void Main(string[] args) { int result = new CalMethod().Calculator(1, 2); }`

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really a good place to learn the basics of a programming language. I recommend picking up a good book or finding a good tutorial online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call for `int result = Calculator(2,3);` should be inside a method, in C# any code should be inside a class method

```
public class CalMethod
    {
        int x;
        int y;

        public int Calculator(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public void TheClient()
        {
            int result = Calculator(2,3);  
        }    
    }
```

Comment: @Jackie Ma - This is one way to do it. If you implement this or another solution, come back and edit your question, or post a new one. But be sure to search the site before posting a new question. Thanks, and good luck.

Comment: 1. I tried encapsulating this ' int result= Calculator (2,3); ' in a new method as what logr suggested; 2. Using the lambda expression: 'int g=> Calculator (2,3); '  Thank you, canton7, lgor and ryanwebjackson